# Permission denied when trying to draw data from a table in IE

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, download, vba

I have just recently started looking at applications of VBA in Excel accessing web pages through IE, and have no experience with html coding, so the solution to this might be really simple...

I have a section of code (below) that is supposed to navigate to a website, access a table and pull out the data into excel. However, at seemingly random times, for no reason that I can determine, the Object Variable 'TDelement' becomes locked somehow, and Excel throws up an Error 70: Permission Denied when I try to access the next cell through the loop. It doesn't happen all the time, and it doesn't happen on the same table cell.

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim TDElements As Object
Dim TDelement As Object
Dim Web_Address As String
Dim DteTm As Date

Web_Address = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDQ65388/IDQ65388.040762.tbl.shtml"

' Access the Webpage
    IE.Navigate Web_Address
' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
       Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
' Find and Set Data Table Cells/object within webpage
     Set TDElements = IE.document.GetElementsByTagName("td")
' Pull each TDElement (table cell) from TDElements
     Rw = 1
     Col = 2
     For Each TDelement In TDElements
        If Col = 1 Then
           Col = 2
        ElseIf Col = 2 Then
           Col = 1
        End If
        If Col = 1 Then
           DteTm = TDelement.innerText
           Worksheets(1).Cells(Rw, Col).Value = DteTm
        ElseIf Col = 2 Then
           Worksheets(1).Cells(Rw, Col).Value = TDelement.innerText
        End If
        If Col = 2 Then
           Rw = Rw + 1
        End If
     Next
```

If the error is going to occur within a cycle of the loop, it occurs on either

`DteTm = TDelement.innerText` or

`Worksheets(1).Cells(Rw, Col).Value = TDelement.innerText`,

dependant on the outcome of the `If...Then` statement, obviously.

After a bit of googling, the general concensus seemed to be that error 70 is related to naming conflicts with variables (ie trying to use the same variable name twice). Because of this I tried adding `Set TDelement = Nothing` before `Next` to clear the variable at the end of each loop, but it didn't resolve the issue (not all that surprising; I have never had an issue with variables in loops like this before).

Could it have something to do with `.innerText`? Even though it is mentioned on just about every forum post that I have seen with regards to pulling data from IE, it isn't mentioned in the Excel help files at all...

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, apologies if I have missed anything, it's been a while since I have posted... Let me know if you need more details on anyhting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub sample()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Web_Address As String

    Dim tblTR As Object
    Dim tblTD As Object


    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    Web_Address = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDQ65388/IDQ65388.040762.tbl.shtml"

    ' Access the Webpage
    IE.Navigate Web_Address
    IE.Visible = True

Start:

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
    Loop
    ' Find and Set Data Table Cells/object within webpage
    Set tblTR = IE.document.GetElementsByTagName("tr")

    If tblTR Is Nothing Then GoTo Start

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    For Each tblTD In tblTR
        If Not tblTD Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = tblTD.all(0).innerText
            Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = tblTD.all(1).innerText
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers for the quick response, and for the far neater method of accessing the table. It's worked like a charm, completely cut out the error I was getting. Is there any chance you could explain why I was running into problems, to avoid anything similar in the future?